# In Asp.Net Core core how to I get the web site's IP address?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

In web forms if I needed to obtain the website server's IP address (say for logging) I could obtain it from `request.ServerVariables["LOCAL_ADDR"]`

How can it be obtain in Asp.Net Core when running in Kestral behind IIS or IIS Express?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpConnectionFeature>()` - [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.features.ihttpconnectionfeature?view=aspnetcore-2.1):

```
var httpConnectionFeature = httpContext.Features.Get<IHttpConnectionFeature>();
var localIpAddress = httpConnectionFeature?.LocalIpAddress;
```

Comment: I get 127.0.0.1

Comment: @Helzgate That is your localhost IP address

Comment: That local ip is what Kestrel listens on even when integrated with IIS.  [MS Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Answer (score 7):

This is what worked for me using .net core 2.1

Adjust the regex to your needs.  My prod web servers are in the 10.168.x.x range.  my dev machine is in the 10.60.x.x range.

```
if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(localIpAddress))
{
    var ips = await System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddressesAsync(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName());

    string rgx = (env.IsDevelopment()) ? @"10{1}\.60{1}\..*" : @"10{1}\.168{1}\..*";
    var result = ips.FirstOrDefault(x => {
        Match m2 = Regex.Match(x.ToString(), rgx);
        return m2.Captures.Count >= 1;
    });
    localIpAddress = result.ToString();
}
```

Although in the end I ended up just using `System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()` because I didn't really need the IP address.

Answer (score 2):

This works for any type of apps asp.net or console only

```
Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList
```

or

```
from if in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
where if.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up
from address in if.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses
select address
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use IHttpContextAccessor class in .net core to get client's ip address

I found solution at this url [How to get client ip address in .net core 2.x](https://bugsncodes.blogspot.com/2019/03/how-to-get-client-ip-address-in-net.html), is simple small code which gives ip address.

Comment: The question asks how to get the website’s IP address not the client’s IP address.